# Source Control for multiple projects/solutions with shared libraries

Tags: version-control, shared-libraries, repository-design

I am currently working on a project to convert a number of Excel VBA powered workbooks to VSTO solutions.  All of the workbooks will share a number of class libraries and third party assemblies, in fact most of the work is done in the class libraries.  I currently have my folder structure laid out like this.

```
Base
    Libraries  
    Assemblies  
    Workbooks  
        Workbook1  
        Workbook2
```

Each of the workbooks will be its own solution, and the workbook solutions just reference the assemblies in the folder structure.  My question is how would you lay out the source control?  Would you start the repository at the base? Or would you create a repository for each workbook solution?  Would you rearrange the folders?

Now that we have the initial development done, we're about to have a bunch of outside developers come on to the project to helps us convert the rest of the workbooks and I really like the idea of them being able to check out from the base directory and having all of the dependencies ready to go.  I also worry that there are other concerns that come with having 20+ solutions/projects under one source control repository.

I want everything to be as simple as possible for people joining the project but I don't want to sacrifice long term usability.  In my mind I've been going back and forth, what's simpler one repository or one repository per solution?

I'd appreciate and insight you have, because I'm fresh out.

Additional Information:  Currently, I am using Mercurial personally, but the project will probably get moved to StarTeam unless I can make some convincing arguments for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention in your question what source control you are using. As it doesn't sound like you need to limit your outside developers access to the rest of the repository I would not bother with setting up multiple repositories. I would assume that unless your code runs into the millions of lines size that repository size is not an issue.

It all depends what functionality your revision control system supports. In subversion you can declare other folders as external and provide a file URL for the content of that folder, this will cause subversion to deal with that folder as a separate repository even though it is within your folder structure.

Comment: I think I see, using the externals make subversion get the most current version of the dependency from an external link.  Since I would like people to be able to load the class library for debugging I should start the repository at the top.  If I didn't I could use externals to import dependencies.